# Reporting on Blocks in Content Elements of 2.3.2

Tags: blocks, reporting

How would I set up reporting on Blocks that are set up in Content Elements of our Magento 2.3.2 website? These blocks contain advertising and I would like to see if customers click on them.

Comment: You add the link/tracker to the banner to track the users.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can use a tool like [Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/) to track the clicks on the banners.
2. You can track with js the *'onclick*' events and make an ajax call to a controller which could record the element and number of clicks on it.
3. You could again use js to track the *'onclick'* event and trigger sending data to dataLayer if you have Google Tag Manager integration.
4. I am not sure where the clients land if they click on the banners, but if it's in another Magento page, then you could append some GET parameters in the URL that the client will be redirected and process those parameters in the controller which manipulates the display of the landing page. This is basically the UTM parameters approach that [Google Analytics](https://blog.hubspot.com/customers/understanding-basics-utm-parameters) uses.
5. Actually use the UTM parameters in an integration with Google Analytics.

Good Luck!